# Can someone explain without a lot of jargon what this time out error means?

Tags: firefox, webmail

I keep getting error messages on emails I'm trying to open, "the remote server 127.0.0.2 was refused or timed out while attempting to connect"  I was on a plane yesterday with a phone in airplane mode, & am now on a laptop if that makes any difference.

I am barely computer literate, so I struggle to make sense of this error message.

Is there anyway to retrieve these emails?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the place where you usually get emails (the server) is not reachable due to your location or laptop's connectivity to the server or internet.

Either that, or your email configuration (settings) are wrong, and need to be reset. 127.0.0.2 is a strange server address.

A server is just a computer that your computer connects to for services, like email service.

If you typically access these emails from the laptop while connected to a specific internal network (looks like you probably do), you won't be able to access them other places.

Comment: 127.0.0.2 would make sense if the laptop is accessing the mail server through stunnel, or through an SSH tunnel, or some other setup that tries to avoid a whole-system VPN.